# Get settings for Distributed Transaction Coordinator (DTC) through the Windows firewall with C# code

Tags: c#, windows, wmi, firewall

I am working on a wpf application for windows 7.
I need to find whether **Distributed Transaction Coordinator(DTC)** is **enabled to work through firewall** in windows 7 with C# code.
 I am using **WMI** queries to find info about other settings but i am not able find a class to use in **WMI** to get the setting(non-firewall settings) for **Distributed Transaction Coordinator(DTC) through firewall.** 
 I do not need to set the value, just need to read the current setting for that.

Comment: Are you tried reading the values of the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MSDTC` key, like the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759136%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) suggest.

Comment: @RRUZ Thanks for the reply. As mentioned here http://www.packtpub.com/article/how-configure-msdtc-firewall-distributed-wcf-service i need to get the configuration of the firewall. Sorry for late reply, i was on vacation.